# tkinter Treeview: get selected item values

Tags: python, tkinter, tree, treeview, row

I'm just starting with a small tkinter tree program in python 3.4.

I'm stuck with **returning the first value of the row selected**.
I have multiple rows with 4 columns and I am calling a function  on left-click on a item:

```
tree.bind('<Button-1>', selectItem)
```

The function:

```
def selectItem(a):
    curItem = tree.focus()
    print(curItem, a)
```

This gives me something like this:

```
I003 <tkinter.Event object at 0x0179D130>
```

It looks like the selected item gets identified correctly.
All I need now is how to get the first value in the row.

tree-creation:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def selectItem():
    pass

root = Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=("size", "modified"))
tree["columns"] = ("date", "time", "loc")

tree.column("date", width=65)
tree.column("time", width=40)
tree.column("loc", width=100)

tree.heading("date", text="Date")
tree.heading("time", text="Time")
tree.heading("loc", text="Loc")
tree.bind('<Button-1>', selectItem)

tree.insert("","end",text = "Name",values = ("Date","Time","Loc"))

tree.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you add the code for creating the tree? (or something shorter but similar if it is too long)

Comment: added the tree-creation script. It's not my whole program but the basi cpart of it.

Comment: It seems like the callback is executed before the focus in the tree changes, so you always get the previously selected value.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that might be true, but the first problem I have is still : how du i return the value in the first column of the selected row?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To get the selected item and all its attributes and values, you can use the `item` method:

```
def selectItem(a):
    curItem = tree.focus()
    print tree.item(curItem)
```

This will output a dictionary, from which you can then easily retrieve individual values:

```
{'text': 'Name', 'image': '', 'values': [u'Date', u'Time', u'Loc'], 'open': 0, 'tags': ''}
```

Also note that the callback will be executed *before* the focus in the tree changed, i.e. you will get the item that *was* selected before you clicked the new item. One way to solve this is to use the event type `ButtonRelease` instead.

```
tree.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', selectItem)
```

Comment: how to get  particular value from output dictionary? can you please explain.

Comment: Perfect, simple, useful

Comment: Nisarg Parekh: tree.item(curItem, 'text') and tree.item(curItem)['text'] will both retrieve the 'text' element for that item.

If you want to alter the other columns one at a time, instead of using tree.item(curItem, 'values') or tree.item(curItem, values=['new', 'values', 'here']) you can use tree.set(curItem, 'time') to retrieve or tree.set(curItem, time='value') to change.

Comment: `ttk.treeview.focus()` returns the current focus item. That means the item that was last selected. `ttk.treeview.selection()` returns a tuple of all the selected items.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good example of getting information of a row selected in a python tkinter treeview. Allow me to represent a final neat coding discussed here. I use python 3.8

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def selectItem(a):
    curItem = tree.focus()
    print(tree.item(curItem))

root = Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=("size", "modified"))
tree["columns"] = ("date", "time", "loc")

tree.column("date", width=65)
tree.column("time", width=40)
tree.column("loc", width=100)

tree.heading("date", text="Date")
tree.heading("time", text="Time")
tree.heading("loc", text="Loc")
tree.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', selectItem)

tree.insert("","end",text = "Name",values = ("Date","Time","Loc"))

tree.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Ther result is

```
{'text': 'Name', 'image': '', 'values': ['Date', 'Time', 'Loc'], 'open': 0, 'tags': ''}
```

You can copy, paste and try it. It's good.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to get row as {column name:value pair}:

```
def selectItem(a):
    curRow = tree.set(a)
    loc_value = curRow["loc"]
```

Or you want to get cell value by column name

```
def selectItem(a):
    loc_value = tree.set(a, column="loc")
```

Answer (score 0):

`ttk.treeview.focus()` returns the current focus item. That means the item that was last selected.

`ttk.treeview.selection()` returns a tuple of all the selected items.