# Actions with selected elements tkinter python

Tags: tkinter

The essence of the question is why when using the function

```
def OnDoubleClick(self, event):
    print(self.tree.item(self.tree.focus()))
```

couldn't get the value data? When using "tree.get_children", then it outputs the values, but all without order.
As far as I understand, to get all the attributes in the list, need to execute the "focus" and "item" method, only in my case it is not possible to use it because the output is empty

Could there be a problem due to the use of mysql?

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Main(tk.Frame):
    def OnDoubleClick(self, event):
        pass

    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.db = db
        toolbar = tk.Frame(bg='#d7d8e0', bd=2)
        toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=('ID', 'Name', 'input_data'), height=60, show='headings')
        self.tree.column('ID', width=60, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('Name', width=500, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('input_data', width=500, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('ID', text='№')
        self.tree.heading('Name', text='Name')
        self.tree.heading('input_data', text='Input data')
        self.db.c.execute('''
            SELECT id_Application, 
                (SELECT name_organisation FROM database_client WHERE 
                    database_client.email == database_client_application.email),
            input_data FROM database_client_application''')
        [self.tree.delete(i) for i in self.tree.get_children()]
        [self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=row) for row in self.db.c.fetchall()]
        self.tree.pack()
        self.tree.bind("<Double-1>", lambda event: self.OnDoubleClick(event))

class DB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    db = DB()
    app = Main(root)
    w = root.winfo_screenwidth() // 2
    h = root.winfo_screenheight() // 2
    root.geometry('1000x900+{}+{}'.format(w - 500, h - 450))
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614279/python-tkinter-tree-get-selected-item-values - Similar article

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Also, try to explain more about what you have done to debug this. Have you verified that `self.tree.focus()` is returning what you expect. If it is, have you verified that `self.tree.item(...)` is returning what you expect?

Comment: Fixed and tried to explain more.