# tkinter Treeview: pass event and variable to another function in another module

Tags: python, tkinter

I have problem when passing Tk treeview event to another module. I will demonstrate problem on a code from already answered question from KokoEfraim [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614279/tkinter-treeview-get-selected-item-values).

I have main module with the same code except for function `selectItem`, which I put into Functions.py:

Main.py:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import Main_functions as Main_functions

root = Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=("size", "modified"))
tree["columns"] = ("date", "time", "loc")

tree.column("date", width=65)
tree.column("time", width=40)
tree.column("loc", width=100)

tree.heading("date", text="Date")
tree.heading("time", text="Time")
tree.heading("loc", text="Loc")
tree.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', Main_functions.selectItem)

tree.insert("","end",text = "Name",values = ("Date","Time","Loc"))

tree.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Main_functions:

```
from tkinter import *

def selectItem(a):
    curItem = tree.focus()
    print(tree.item(curItem))
```

With this comes my problem, because I receive error `NameError: name 'tree' is not defined`, because unlike in the original, I put the `selectItem` function into another .py and therefore the tree is not recognized there.

Which brings me to a question, am I able to pass into `selectItem` a variable? Because putting more variables into the function raises error with too many passed variables, as event is not passed in a standard way.

I have tried another solution such as `a.widget.focus`, but non are working.

Comment: `a.widget.focus()` should work in your case.  But you need to change `tree.item(curItem)` to `a.widget.item(curItem)` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, `selectItem` will be passed an object representing the event. One of the attributes of that object is a reference to the widget that received the event. So, you can write your `selectItem` method to use that information:

```
def selectItem(event):
    tree = event.widget
    curItem = tree.focus()
    print(tree.item(curItem))
```